# Why is this code not displaying my photo on the page?

Tags: php, image, echo

if my query is working fine by fetch the data from the database.
The variables are working fine as well. The name for the image in the database is stored in the post_banner column. please note that the original file is stored in the server folder only the image name is sent to the database.

if the variable is like this:
*$featured_post_image = $post['post_banner'];*

```
<?php echo "<img  class='img_ft' src='content/newsimages/'".$featured_post_image."' alt='$featured_post_image'> "; ?>
```

This code is not display the image from the sever folder. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just a problem with single and double quotes.

your line

```
<?php echo "<img  class='img_ft' src='content/newsimages/'".$featured_post_image."' alt='$featured_post_image'> "; ?>
```

Should be

```
<?php echo "<img  class='img_ft' src='content/newsimages/".$featured_post_image."' alt='$featured_post_image'> "; ?>
```

Please note the absence of a quote after `/newsimages/`

Comment: The image path variable is being concatenated with to directory path, there is a single quote which is from the src=' and concatenated using a double quote src='".imagesrc."', this should work but it is not.

Comment: I tried this your answer code: <?php echo "<img  class='img_ft' src='content/newsimages/".$featured_post_image."' alt='$featured_post_image'> "; ?>
 but is not working. Please note that I'm using IE 11.